# How to impose conditions on a "GROUP BY" statement - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM products
 WHERE catalog = 1
 GROUP BY style
 ORDER BY name ASC
 limit 0, 100
```

Since I have multiple products with the same "style", this will return information about whatever the first product that has a certain "style" (through the GROUP BY condition).

Because some products have a "discount", my **question is as follows**: *HOW do I make it so that the "GROUP BY style" condition gives first priority to a product that has a discount? My ultimate goal is to use 1 query instead of after that going through each returned style and checking if there is any products with a discount*

If I specify "GROUP BY style, discount", it returns 2 products with the same style: 1 with and 1 without a discount. This is NOT something that I need -- I need to return only 1 match (unique) style but give preference to those items that match this style that have a discount.

Comment: What do you mean by "preference"?  Do you only want results that have a discount or do you want them ordered by discount first and then the rest of the results?

Comment: @wes: I want results to have discount BUT if there is no discount, I still want to get results.

Comment: if the output for a given style is [normal, discounted] return only [discounted] but if its just [normal] return [normal]?

Comment: @Dan: exactly. not sure how to put that into a query.

Comment: do you need any product with discount or a product with highest discount?

Comment: @piotrm: ANY discount will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot impose priority within groupped set in a single query. You can restrict your results by using WHERE before applying GROUP BY, but that will just strip your result of rows not satisfying WHERE condition. To find order within groupped sets use a query like this: (assuming id is the primary key here)

```
SELECT p.* FROM
  ( SELECT style,max(discount) as highest_discount 
    FROM products
    WHERE catalog = 1
    GROUP BY style ) p1
JOIN products p
ON p.id =
  ( SELECT pu.id 
    FROM products pu
    WHERE pu.catalog = 1
      AND pu.style = p1.style
      AND pu.discount = p1.highest_discount
    LIMIT 1 )
```

Comment: Piotrm, this worked like a charm. However, it took ~6 seconds on my system (and 2.7 seconds on production server) to process the query AND that's considering that I limited it to 0,12. Pretty much it's the same, or slower than running 2 queries.

Comment: It shouldn't be so slow, try EXPLAIN to see if indices are being properly used.

Comment: ALTER TABLE products ADD INDEX (catalog,style,discount);

Comment: that's wicked. under 1 second on my test machine. I guess I should look into optimizing my tables. thanks again! great answer.

Comment: Corrected answer, there was select *, in the first subquery, but all that is needed to reference to 2nd subquery is just style,max(discount)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the "HAVING" clause. It should get you closer.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

When you say "priority to a product that has a discount", priority implies ordering, not grouping.  You need to order your results by `discount` (which I am assuming is a column, and not a table).

Comment: I want results to give me a field that has discount > 0. if no items with discount exist, I still want to get results. see, I am not sure HOW the "GROUP BY" statements chooses what exact product's information (out of all products that have a given style) to show.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done with a `HAVING` clause; assuming discount table is boolean, 1 for discount, 0 for no discount:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  products 
WHERE 
  catalog = 1 
GROUP BY 
  style 
HAVING
  discount = MAX(discount)
ORDER BY 
  name ASC limit 0, 100
```

---

edit: I may have misread the question. If all you want is for those items wich have a discount to appear first in your list you would only need to change the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  products 
WHERE 
  catalog = 1 
GROUP BY 
  style 
ORDER BY 
  discount DESC,
  name ASC 
LIMIT 
  0, 100
```

Comment: thanks but none of these queries product the wanted result. piotrm's solution above does the job.